# includeCssFile and includeJsFile doesn't output {{ siteUrl }}

Tags: templating

It seems that when calling a CSS or JS file include, if the path contains {{ siteUrl }} it outputs {{ siteUrl }} in the html that is generated.

Like so;
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ siteUrl }}css/styles.css"/>`

Which should be (for example);
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://site.url/dev/css/styles.css"/>`

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: never had that happening to me, are you sure you don't have quotes around your siteUrl so it's just a string? like this: {{'siteUrl'}}? Either way, I don't it's necessary to add your full url to your assets paths. You can just point to them like href="/css/styles.css"

Comment: Can you provide the code you use for `includeCssFile` and `includeJsFile`?

Comment: This is the code; `{% includeCssFile "{{ siteUrl }}css/modul.min.css" %}` and `{% includeJsFile "{{ siteUrl }}js/ui.min.js" %}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to output Twig variables inside another Twig tag, you shouldn't include the braces around the variable.

So this:

```
{% includeCssFile "{{ siteUrl }}css/modul.min.css" %}
{% includeJsFile "{{ siteUrl }}js/ui.min.js" %}
```

Should be this:

```
{% includeCssFile siteUrl ~ "css/modul.min.css" %}
{% includeJsFile siteUrl ~ "js/ui.min.js" %}
```

These examples use the [concatenation operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators) (`~`) to join the value held in the `siteUrl` variable to the string holding the path to the CSS or JS file to be included.